# Iterating out the values in a list of dictionaries PYTHON

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, iteration

I have a list of dictionaries. Each has a key, and a 3 value list.  Each value is an ADC reading, I have a function to take and spit out the converted value.

I would like to take each value and convert it with this function, however.

```
for value in my_list[0].itervalues():
  print value
```

This prints the values as a list, but I want to take each value individually and pass it off to the function to be converted

```
 for value in my_list:
      print value
```

This prints out each dictionary

I am not sure how to nest these loops all together to take the individual values and append the current list of dictionaries with the converted values or generate a separate list of dictionaries altogether.  Appending would be more efficient I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function to apply your function on all value items :

```
for value in my_list[0].itervalues():
  print map(your_func,value)
```

And if you want to create a new dictionary you can do it within a dict comprehension :

```
new_dict={k:map(your_func,val) for k, val in your_dict.iteritems()}
```

Also you may note that this depends on your function signature and your values for example if your function accept more than 1 argument you can not use `map` here.

Example :

```
>>> def my_func(a,b):
...   return a+b
... 
>>> l=[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
>>> map(my_func,l)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: my_func() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

In that case you can use a list comprehension :

```
>>> [my_func(i,j) for i,j in l]
[3, 7, 11]
```

Comment: That works, but to append each dictionary with the new values?

Comment: @cc6g11 In that case you can use a dict comprehension! check the edit!

Comment: what if I need to pass 2 arguments.  Like before the values in the dictionary, but also along with the keys of each dictionary.@Kasra